# LaTeX: How to find package(s) that a command belongs to?

Tags: search, latex, command

It is a simple question to which I am not able to find the answer:

Given a LaTeX **command**, how do I find out what **package**(s) it belongs to or comes from?

For example, given the `\qquad` horizontal spacing command, what package does it come from? Especially troublesome since it works without including any package!

Comment: `\qquad` comes from TeX (i.e. from the very core), so there is no need for some special LaTeX package to allow you using it.

Comment: Noram: I am a bit OCD like that. I like to know the original package and documentation for any command I use. I do the same with MSDN when I use Microsoft APIs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> Given a LaTeX command, how do I find out what package(s) it belongs to or comes from?

Consult your references:

1. If it's in the index to the TeXbook, it's inherited from TeX, the engine that drives LaTeX.
2. Otherwise, if it's in the index to the LaTeX manual, it's probably defined in `latex.ltx` or in one of the standard class files, not in a package.
3. Otherwise, if it's in the index to *The LaTeX Companion*, the page number probably tells you what package it's from.
4. Otherwise, you could do some fancy grepping on the results of `find /usr/share/texmf -name '*.sty'`, but be prepared for a painful exercise.
5. Or, you could ask on http://stackoverflow.com.  But then some idiot will respond by asking why you want to know...

Answer (score 10):

You can search http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/ for that information and more.

Remember that LaTeX is a macro language on top of TeX, and all the macros are made up of TeX which doesn't need to be imported. `\qquad` is in that category.

Answer (score 8):

As far as I know, there is no really good general answer to this.  But there are a number of techniques you might try for any given command.  In the case of `\qquad`, it's part of basic TeX.  Remember that you can always use TeX in interactive mode:

```
$ tex '\show\qquad'
This is TeX, Version 3.141592 (Web2C 7.5.6)
> \qquad=macro:
->\hskip 2em\relax .
 \show\qquad

? x
No pages of output.
```

Some macros are added by LaTeX on top of TeX, such as `\begin`:

```
 $ tex '\show\begin'
This is TeX, Version 3.141592 (Web2C 7.5.6)
> \begin=undefined.
 \show\begin

? x
No pages of output.
```

whereas

```
$ latex '\show\begin'
This is pdfTeXk, Version 3.141592-1.40.3 (Web2C 7.5.6)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
entering extended mode
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, usenglishmax, dumylang, noh
yphenation, greek, monogreek, ancientgreek, ibycus, pinyin, loaded.
> \begin=macro:
#1->\@ifundefined {#1}{\def \reserved@a {\@latex@error {Environment #1 undefine
d}\@eha }}{\def \reserved@a {\def \@currenvir {#1}\edef \@currenvline {\on@line
 }\csname #1\endcsname }}\@ignorefalse \begingroup \@endpefalse \reserved@a .
 \show\begin

? x
No pages of output.
```

Everything else comes from packages.  If you really wanna know which package a macro comes from (other than by google or grepping your texmf tree), you can check after each package you load whether it's defined.  Try defining this before any `\usepackage` commands:

```
\let\oldusepackage\usepackage
\renewcommand\usepackage[1]{
  \oldusepackage{#1}
  \ifcsname includegraphics\endcsname
    \message{^^Jincludegraphics is defined in #1^^J}
    \let\usepackage\oldusepackage
  \fi}
```

Then when you run `latex` on your `.tex` file, look for a line in the output that says `includegraphics is defined in graphicx`.  It's not likely, but some devious packages might do bad things with `\usepackage` so there's a chance this might not work.  Another alternative would be to simply define the command you're interested in before loading any packages:

```
\newcommand\includegraphics{}
```

Then you might get an error message when the package that defines the command is loading.  This is actually less reliable than the former approach, since many packages use `\def` and `\let` to define their macros rather than `\newcommand`, bypassing the "already-defined" check.  You could also just insert a check by hand in between each load:

```
\ifcsname includegraphics\endcsname\message{^^Jdefined after graphicx^^J}\fi
```

Answer (score 4):

Due to lack of reputation I cannot comment on Steve's answer, which was very helpful to me, but I would like to extend it a bit.

First, in his second approach (fiddling with `usepackage`) the case where `usepackage` has optional arguments is not dealt with. Secondly, packages are often loaded by other packages via `RequirePackage` which makes it hard to find the actual place of definition of a command. So my refinement of Steve's answer is:

```
\usepackage{xargs}
\let\oldusepackage\usepackage
\let\oldRequirePackage\RequirePackage
\renewcommandx{\usepackage}[3][1,3]{
  \oldusepackage[#1]{#2}[#3]
  \ifcsname includegraphics\endcsname
    \message{^^Jincludegraphics is defined in #2^^J}
    \let\usepackage\oldusepackage
    \let\RequirePackage\oldRequirePackage
  \fi}
\renewcommandx{\RequirePackage}[3][1,3]{
  \oldRequirePackage[#1]{#2}[#3]
  \ifcsname includegraphics\endcsname
    \message{^^Jincludegraphics is defined in #2^^J}
    \let\usepackage\oldusepackage
    \let\RequirePackage\oldRequirePackage
  \fi}
```

The `xargs` package is used here to get the unusual options of `usepackage` right (first and third parameter are optional).

Putting this directly after `documentclass` should tell where `includegraphics` is defined.